# How calculate $ \int_C \bar {z} ^2dz$ if $C$ is a circle such that $ |z| = 1 $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

How calculate $ \int_C \bar {z} ^2dz$ if $C$ is a circle such that  $ |z| = 1 $

for $z=x+iy \in C$

$\int\limits_{C}{\bar{z}^2 \ dz}=\int\limits_{C}({(x-iy) \ (dx+i\:dy))^2}= \int\limits_{C} \left(xa+yb+ixb-iya\right)^2= \\
 \int\limits_{C}{\left(a^2x^2-b^2x^2+4abxy+b^2y^2-a^2y^2\right)}+i\int\limits_{C}{(\left(2abx^2-2a^2xy+2b^2xy-2aby^2\right)} $

I don't know if I'm on the right track and how to use the fact that the circumference has radius 1

Comment: If $|z| = 1$, $z = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$, $\overline{z} = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta}$.  And squaring that is easy too.

Comment: if the radius is $1$, then $\overline{z}=\frac{1}{z}$. This is a very neat trick which allows you to deduce the integral is 0.

Comment: I'm unclear what $a,b$ mean in your rewrite of the integral.  I think the problem may have been a [contour integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration) around the unit circle:  $$ \oint\limits_{C}\overline{z}^2 \mathrm{d}z $$

Answer (score 2):

Since $|z| = 1$, $z\bar z = 1$. Therefore, you may write $$\int_C \bar z^2 \, dz = \int_C \frac{dz}{z^2}$$
It is well known that
$$\int_C \frac{dz}{z^2} = 0$$
since $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has a primitive for $z\ne 0$, namely $-\frac{1}{z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterize by $z=e^{i\theta}$, for $0\leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$. Then $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ so $\bar{z}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta=\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)=e^{-i\theta}.$ It is easy to see then that $z'(\theta)=ie^{i\theta}$ so
\begin{align}
\int_C\bar{z}^2dz=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}d\theta=0.
\end{align}
Of course, as @peek-a-boo suggested, we also know that $\bar{z}^2=1/z^2,$ which has an antiderivative function around the unit circle, so integrates to zero.